# How do I move a https site to localhost?

Tags: 7, ssl

I am moving a site from the live server where it has an SSL certificate and is accessed by HTTPS to my localhost. After moving the site over, I get an ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

I am uncertain of how to fix the issue. I tried turning off Clean URLs before the move. And I also tried changing the .htaccess file.

Comment: Pretty broad but my first guess is the local server is not setup to respond to traffic on 443 and or , you have no local certificate installed. May want to ask at ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

As Kevin suggested in the comments, I did not have a local certificate installed. Using MAMP, I ended up following [the instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318467/configuring-mamp-for-ssl) to solve the issue.